# Image recovery from binary file

Tags: python

The objective is to extract an image from of a binary file. How do I search a binary file for the filetype's markers, SOI and EOI.
Regular find() functions don't seem to work as I cannot load the binary file as a string.

Comment: Knowing what kind of image would help.

Comment: Match the magic number, `0xff 0xd8` for jpeg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming) and others.

Comment: What's keeping you from loading the file as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to search a magic word in a stream (not string).

Here's the idea:

read one char a time (use file.read(1)) from this file
use a queue length of your magic word, check the queue for each read

```
MAGIC_WORD = r'JPEG'  # it's example... just example
l = list(c for c in f.read(len(MAGIC_WORD)))
offset = 0
while True:
    if ''.join(l) == MAGIC_WORD:
        return offset
        offset += 1
        l.pop(0)
        l.append(f.read(1))
```

If you feel the need... I mean, the need for speed, check [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) article, use a smarter algorithm, and finally switch to c++.

Sorry I don't know any presenting python library that does this. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Another think:

if you can use unix shell (instead of Python), you can try to use unix pipes and chain some search tools (like grep and xxd)

like

```
cat yourbinfile | xxd -p | grep HEXMAGICWORD
```

where HEXMAGICWORD is

```
echo jpeg | xxd -p
```

I'm not very familiar with shell, so it's not exact answer.